# How to break from a function and rejoin at that point

Tags: c#

I remember learning at some point that you exit a function at a point, and then call that function again to rejoin at the point you left off. Is there any way you can do this within c#?

thanks

blueblob0

Comment: Can you please add some example of what exactly you are trying to do? The one answer below suggests a way but that is limited to returning a value. To me it doesn't look exactly like what you are asking of. So an example will be useful...

Comment: To say that yield is limited to returning a value is like saying LINQ methods are limited to returning values. While technically true, I'm not sure what it adds to any discussion. I'll readily admit it's a simple example of `yield`, but it's a simple question.

Comment: I want to have the function have some initialization stuff then a while loop and then some ending stuff, i want to be able to stop the function each time it reaches the end of the loop and then call it again to  do another loop.

Comment: @jdphenix: This was not even a discussion with you. Your answer isn't wrong but are you sure you are answering the question? There are multiple ways in which this question can be interpreted and I'm only asking for further clarity.

Comment: @displayName Perhaps only partially answered indeed... clarity would help in getting better answers, but I can really only interpret "exit a functions ... call that function again and rejoin at the point you left off" as the jeopardy answer to "What is yield return in C#?" For what we know it may be the last piece in the puzzle for blueblob0 in implementing their solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantically I believe you're asking about `yield`,

for example:

```
IEnumerable<int> Squares()
{
    for (var i = 1; i < Int32.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        yield return i * i; 
    }
}

// ... usage
Squares().Take(5); // Gets the first five squares, execution state of 
                   // of Squares() is kept in a state machine the 
                   // compiler creates for you behind the scenes. 
Sqaures().Take(5); // Gets the next five squares.
```

Comment: Yield was what i needed to use in the end thanks